# how to Sum the max from two keys similarly, object javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, sum, max

I need the sum total of the object, where, but the maximum of each similar pair
**javascript**

```
var score = {
    "work_1": 5,
    "work_1|pm": 10,
    "work_2": 8,
    "work_2|pm": 7
    "work_3": 10
};
```

*the work_3 doesn't have a pair similar*
I wish this result

**total = 28**

Comment: So, just calculate the max, and add? What is the problem?

Comment: i need the sum of the total object by max pair,

Comment: I understand what you need, but why doesn't it work for you? What is the problem you have *in trying*?

Comment: Why is the total 28? What is a "similar pair"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the maximums by key-prefix in a new object, and then sum the values of that object. In both phases you can use `reduce`:

```js
var score = {
    "work_1": 5,
    "work_1|pm": 10,
    "work_2": 8,
    "work_2|pm": 7,
    "work_3": 10
};

var result = Object.values(
    Object.entries(score).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
        k = k.split("|")[0];
        acc[k] = Math.max(v, acc[k] ?? v);
        return acc;
    }, {})
).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the property values of the object with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), sort the resulting array, then sum the first 2 items:

```js
var score = {
    "work_1": 5,
    "work_1|pm": 10,
    "work_2": 8,
    "work_2|pm": 7,
    "work_3": 10
};

const max2 = Object.values(score).sort().splice(0, 2)

const result = max2[0] + max2[1];
console.log(result)
```